# something wrong with my heap sorting

Tags: c++, heapsort

I'm wondering what's wrong with my heap sorting code?
I just did what's common;read an array,called heapify,deleted the root for each node and printed it.
but it didn't work.

```
void heapsort(int *a,int n)
{
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {

        cout << "Enter a["<<i<<"] :";
        cin >> a[i];
    }

    system("cls");

    for(int i=n/2;i>0;i--)
    {
        heapify(i,a,n);
    }

    for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout << deleteheap(a,n);
    }
}


void heapify(int i,int *a,int n)
{
    int l=2*i,r=2*i+1,largest,temp;
    if(l<=n && r<=n)
    {

        largest=l;
        if(a[r]>a[l])
        {
            largest=r;
        }
        if(a[i]<largest)
        {

            temp=a[i];
            a[i]=a[largest];
            a[largest]=temp;

        }

        heapify(largest,a,n);

    }
}


int deleteheap(int *a,int n)
{

    int i=0,x=a[1],k=a[n];n--;
    for(int j=2 , i=1;j<=n;)
    {

        if(j<n)
        {
            if(a[j]<a[j+1])
                j++;
        }
        if(k>=a[j])
            break;
        a[i]=a[j];
        i=j;
        j*=2;

    }

    a[i]=k;
    return x;
 }
```

Comment: "but it didn't work." Please be specific.

Comment: first of all i think there should be a problem in heapify function

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debugging info (e.g. `g++ -Wall -g`) and **use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb` ...)

Comment: i mean here if(l<=n && r<=n)

Comment: @dark-sky: What do you mean by it didn't work? Did it produce unexpected/ incorrect outcome or, did nothing at all? Please mention the exact form of the problem.

Comment: "Compile with all warnings and debugging info"

Comment: Basile Starynkevitch , if you mean it has warning,i checked and it was ok ,compiler couldn't any warnings or errors

Comment: dear bgamlath,it runs without errors but it doesn't make a heap , i tried to cout after heapifying so entered 2,17,13,2,12 but output wasn't a heap

Comment: @darksky - For starters, most of your for-loops look dicey.  It's like you didn't take into account that C/C++ indexes arrays starting at index 0 (and the last valid element is typically a[n-1]).

Comment: come on man I know but I think heaps start with 1 to n because if use 0 to n-1 we can have problems with right and left children(if root is 0 then r=2*i+1 and l=2*i both will be 0!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have the rep to comment, but i think the mistake is in heapify():

```
if(a[i]<largest)
{
```

should be:

```
if(a[i]<a[largest])
{
```

as others commented, please explain in more detail what doesn't work according to you next time you ask a question.